# What is document in JavaScript and what is its scope?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var document = "temp";

function showDocument()
{
    alert(document); // temp or HTML DOM Document
}
```

It showed "HTML DOM Document" for me, which should be the case. Is it an object, reserved keyword, read-only object?

If it's an object, it should be editable. If it's a reserved keyword, JavaScript should throw an error/exception. If it's read-only, how can I modify the DOM itself which is accessible through `document` only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a read-only property of the global (`window`) object. Its value is a native object representing the current HTML/XML/whatever document loaded into the window.

To modify the DOM, use [DOM manipulation APIs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM)

*edit* — to clarify, the "document" property of the `window` object (or, if you prefer, the global variable called "document") is **itself** immutable, and its value cannot be changed by JavaScript. The value, however, is a *reference* to an object, an object that is mutable in all sorts of ways.

Comment: If document is a read property, how does it happen that we say,

    document.getElementById('someDIV').style.background = 'red';

If document is read only, how am I able to execute this statement.

Comment: A read-only property (in this case, you also could say *variable*) pointing to an object does not mean that the object is not mutable. You can't modify the "pointer", but you can modify the DOM tree.