# What exactly is document in Javascript

Tags: javascript

We always use `document.getElementById()`or `$(document).ready()` or something else like it in Javascript and jQuery.

So, can anyone please tell me what object exactly means in this context. Somewhere, I've read that its a object but was not able to figure out what kind of object it is.

If any one does know, please explain it briefly.

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13860916/1211329) can answer your question.

Comment: See document as the entire page (All HTML controls), document.ready is a function that is called when the page has loaded the controls.  `document.getElementById` is a function that returns a document object, i.e. an input box, a div, a button.

Comment: Google: `mdn document` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document

Comment: Btw, `document.ready` does not exist. Maybe you meant `$(document).ready` but that's jQuery and doesn't have anything to do with `document`.

Comment: Why you guys have voted this question down voted..

Answer (score 0):

> Each HTML document loaded into a browser window becomes a Document
>   object.
>   The Document object provides access to all HTML elements in a page,
>   from within a script.
>   from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)
>
> Legacy DOM was limited in the kinds of elements that could be
>   accessed. Form, link and image elements could be referenced with a
>   hierarchical name that began with the root document object. A
>   hierarchical name could make use of either the names or the sequential
>   index of the traversed elements. For example, a form input element
>   could be accessed as either "document.formName.inputName" or
>   "document.forms[0].elements[0]."

see [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

Answer (score 0):

The `document` object (or rather its interface) is part of the [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#i-Document) and represents the whole, ehm, document.

> The `Document` interface represents the entire HTML or XML document. Conceptually, it is the root of the document tree, and provides the primary access to the document's data.
>
> Since elements, text nodes, comments, processing instructions, etc. cannot exist outside the context of a `Document`, the `Document` interface also contains the factory methods needed to create these objects. The Node objects created have a `ownerDocument` attribute which associates them with the Document within whose context they were created.

The browser provides a JavaScript implementation of the DOM API so that JavaScript code can interact with the web page.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document):

> Each web page loaded in the browser has its own `document` object. This object serves as an entry point to the web page's content (the DOM tree, including elements such as `<body>` and `<table>`) and provides functionality global to the document (such as obtaining the page's URL and creating new elements in the document).

---

Note that this object is not part of JavaScript (the language) itself. It's a consequence of the browser implementing the DOM API in JavaScript.